# command-line flow-based pcap file viewr tools

Tags: tcp, wireshark, pcap, network-traffic

I need some command-line tool which prints a captured pcap file flow-based as follows:
src-ip src-port dst-ip dst-port protocol(tcp/udp) duration number-of-packet
now, I use captcp it is perfect,but it has a main problem:
it hasn't been designed for UDP traffic and you will get error while running pure UDP pcap file.

[I need something like this(it is CAPTCP but with support to UDP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnhWg.png)

I eager to all your comments,but best of them are those itroduce tools!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *tshark* to read the PCAP file and script the aggregation.  This isn't an option for huge PCAP files (several GBs) but the following worked in my tests:

```
#!/bin/sh
PCAP="mypackets.pcap"

tshark -r "$PCAP" -T fields -e ip.addr udp | 
sort |
uniq |
while read x; do
    left=${x%%,*};
    right=${x##*,};
    echo;
    echo "==================";
    echo "$left -> $right";
    tshark -r "$PCAP" -T text ip.src==$left and ip.dst==$right 2>/dev/null;
done
```

Results with internal IPs (censored in a couple of places):

```
192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.19
  5 0.905186262  192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.19 NBNS 92 Name query NBSTAT ...
  6 0.905274977 192.168.0.19 -> 192.168.0.1  ICMP 120 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
773 54.218903171  192.168.0.1 -> 192.168.0.19 NBNS 92 Name query NBSTAT ...
774 54.218991396 192.168.0.19 -> 192.168.0.1  ICMP 120 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

==================
192.168.0.19 -> 192.168.0.19
  6 0.905274977 192.168.0.19 -> 192.168.0.1  ICMP 120 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
774 54.218991396 192.168.0.19 -> 192.168.0.1  ICMP 120 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

==================
192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8
  7 7.527339007 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x3321 A
  8 7.527426252 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xcbe7 AAAA
  9 7.527479187 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xc470 A
 60 7.865822939 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xe7f7 A
 61 7.865862640 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xf994 AAAA
137 7.993523685 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x580c A
138 7.993563877 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x1da8 AAAA
149 8.050389092 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xf953 A
150 8.050429283 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xba7c AAAA
156 8.095814170 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xd808 A
157 8.095853871 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x27bf AAAA
160 8.134157723 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x5970 A
161 8.134196444 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xc00f AAAA
176 8.156413943 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xfe0c A
177 8.156432568 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x8fa1 AAAA
180 8.187659798 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0x9870 A
181 8.187698028 192.168.0.19 -> 8.8.8.8      DNS 79 Standard query 0xb453 AAAA

==================
8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19
 10 7.552742408      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0x3321 A
 11 7.555262701      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0xc470 A
 13 7.559084313      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0xcbe7 AAAA
 69 7.893370696      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0xf994 AAAA
 70 7.895752770      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0xe7f7 A
139 8.016281317      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0x580c A
140 8.017124846      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0x1da8 AAAA
154 8.073028600      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0xf953 A
155 8.078469630      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0xba7c AAAA
158 8.121705259      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0x27bf AAAA
159 8.123310463      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0xd808 A
162 8.149581409      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0x5970 A
163 8.150471991      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0xc00f AAAA
178 8.180086664      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0xfe0c A
179 8.180913038      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0x8fa1 AAAA
212 8.216175579      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 132 Standard query response 0xb453 AAAA
213 8.217023519      8.8.8.8 -> 192.168.0.19 DNS 95 Standard query response 0x9870 A
```

You can then edit the last call to *tshark*, instead of `-T text` you can add `-Tfields` and several `-e` options to get only the fields you need.  For example, you could add another `while` aggregation to count the number of packets (tshark will always output a packet on a single line).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TShark Statistics](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):
tshark -r yourfile.pcap -q -z conv,udp

TShark is part of the [Wireshark distribution](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/).
You can also use [SplitCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap) to split the files.
See also:
 [SplitCap and TShark](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2011/10/splitcap-and-tshark-by-joke-snelders.html)
[Wireshark Statistics](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseStatisticsMenuSection.html)